# Is version item considered as a list item?

Tags: office365, sharepoint-online

Suppose I have a custom sharepoint list. In that list versioning is enabled. I have 5 list items. Out of 5 list item, 1 item is having 3 versions. So how much total count of list items we will get programmatically? 5 or 8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vesion item is a list item version history, it's not consider as a list item.So the list Item total count is 5.

Answer (score 0):

List item version is nothing but data about a particular list item's version. It will be stored as a property of that particular list item and not as a separate list item itself.

So, your total item count will be 5.